# What are the molecular mechanisms behind tachyphylaxis (downregulation of receptors in response to an agonist?)

Tags: molecular-biology

Anyone know of a good source which explains this?  Or is this still an open question?  This wikipedia article describes some molecular biology behind morphine tolerance, but it sounds like its newer research, and isn't fully understood. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_tolerance

I would have thought that something like this would be very well understood.

Answer (score 1):

There are many mechanisms of receptor down-regulation, including internalisation and degradation e.g for the [epidermal growth factor receptor](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12648464?dopt=Abstract&holding=f1000,f1000m,isrctn) and uncoupling via post-translational modifcation e.g. for [G protein-coupled receptors](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev.neuro.27.070203.144206?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori:rid:crossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3dpubmed).

In the case of opioid receptors there is emerging evidence that down-regulation is achieved, at least in part, by [post-transcriptional regulation by a microRNA.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23085997) Presumably this could also accompanied by inactivation of existing receptors, but if the adaptation/desenitisation is long-term then normal receptor turnover may be sufficient.